# How to build .NET Framework ASP.NET app using dotnet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, command-line-interface

We have a mixture of ASP.NET Core and .NET Framework ASP.NET apps.  We use a mixture of `msbuild` and `dotnet` to build the apps.

I'm trying to go all in on `dotnet`, but the build always throws an error of:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview5-011568\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Right now I'm just trying with a very simple command of `dotnet msbuild foo.sln`.  No flags or anything being used for now.

I've tried this on multiple ASP.NET (not Core) apps and they all give the same error.

Comment: `dotnet` is the *.NET Core*-specific tool, MSBuild is the overall build framework that can handle any type of project. Use `msbuild` in the command line instead to build both types of projects, ie `msbuild foo.sln`

Comment: Using "dotnet msbuild" command does not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Web applications, you need to compile using the following code.

```
C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Microsoft Visual Studio'\[year]\[edition]\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe [project.csproj] /p:VisualStudioVersion=[version] /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[profileName]
```

You can run in cmd or PowerShell.
Replace tags according to the version of Visual Studio installed on your machine and solution version.

For Example:

```
C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Microsoft Visual Studio'\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Release
```

Answer (score 0):

We've solved the Microsoft.WebApplication.targets missing reference by adding it as a NuGet dependency, however the dotnet msbuild command still can't compile all related framework and asp.net projects.

We've also stood up our build server inside a docker container on an ubuntu image, as we were hoping to improve our infra with containerization etc.

However we've hit a wall in building all possible projects using the dotnet executable, even though it has the msbuild command built in.

Anyone had any luck with this?
This answer indicates this is not possible though
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366638/6578823