# WPF application build fails with "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method" using MSBuild from SDK 6.0 instead of bundled MSBuild in Rider

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild

I'm using JetBrains Rider to develop WPF application. It builds and executes without any issues from within the IDE or from executable after the release build from within the IDE. However, I need to publish the application as a single file. I tried using the following command:

`dotnet publish -c Release  -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained -p:PublishTrimmed=true`

When I use the bundled MSBuild, it creates a single executable without all the dependent .dll files and other resources. The resulting executable file's size is only 111 KB.

I downloaded SDK 6.0 and changed MSBuild version. I also added the following attributes to .csproj to detect architecture correctly:

```
<GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
<GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
```

After making these changes my project stopped building and I encountered the following errors:

```
  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
  MainWindow.xaml.cs(12, 13): [CS0103] The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
  App.xaml.cs(41, 24): [CS1061] 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'DataContext' and no accessible extension method 'DataContext' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
  App.xaml.cs(42, 24): [CS1061] 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Show' and no accessible extension method 'Show' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have already tried various solutions to resolve these errors, including:

- Setting the build action of `App.xaml` to `ApplicationDefinition` (it was set initially)
- Ensuring that the following ItemGroup is present in the .csproj file (it also existed initially) :

```
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
```

- Adding the `UseWpf` attribute to the .csproj file and setting it to `true`.

Unfortunately, none of these solutions have helped me resolve the errors. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to fix this issue.

**Update**

.csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ProjectGuid>{272EC959-9B24-4026-A24E-4C0158D2C0C1}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WPFApp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WPFApp</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\app_icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>CurrentArchitecture</GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
    <GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>CurrentRuntime</GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
    <StartupObject>WPFApp.App</StartupObject>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <StartupObject>WPFApp.App</StartupObject>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <StartupObject>WPFApp.App</StartupObject>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference ...
  </ItemGroup>
...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="View\MainWindow.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="View\PropertiesWindow.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Commands\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing PublishTrimmed?

Comment: @shingo with bundled MSBuild the result is the same - executable with 111 KB size. Publish with MSBuild from SDK 6.0 ends with the same error as during the build - "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method..."

Comment: This is a .net framework project, so you cannot use dotnet to build it, you need either converting the project to .net core or building with msbuild for .net framework. [What's the difference between using dotnet and MSBuild for building .NET applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349892/whats-the-difference-between-using-dotnet-and-msbuild-for-building-net-applica)

Comment: @shingo I got it. I'm trying to use a different tool for a different type of the project. Interesting.

Comment: Another interesting thing, that when I just change bundled MSBuild to SDK's one, build starts failing. Does it mean, that bundled MSBuild is has different, I dont't know, configuration or something like this?

Comment: There are two versions of msbuild, one for .net framework, one for .net, when you run them you can see the version at the beginning.

Comment: @shingo Thanks a lot. You are right. And now what was wrong is finally clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Single-file publishing requires the target platform to be identified.  If you don't have this now, try adding `-p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64` and/or `-p:PlatformTarget=x64` replacing the correct values for whatever platform you are targeting.  For reference here is a working project file from one of my projects that does the same thing (x86 in this example).

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>annotations</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <StartupObject>MyApp.App</StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\App.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>False</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86</Platforms>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.2.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\App.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\filex16.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SplashScreen Include="Resources\splash.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I tried this `dotnet publish -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 -p:PlatformTarget=x64 -c Release --self-contained` and still it ends with error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method...". Adding attributes you have in the example and I miss (StartupObject, PlatformTarget), still doesn't help.

Comment: I added main part (excluded ItemGroup with long list of references ) of my .csproj.

Comment: Note your entry `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>` means you can't use dotnet as noted in the comment by @shingo